# Detect Element.Style changes with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am at the moment working on a little extension to enhance a website namely the google plus post box. I want to move it to the very left of the monitor.

This post box however resets its values every time it is opened.

Basically I would like to kill off that behavior, and thought I could just monitor the element for element.style changes, and overwrite them again. However DOMAttrModified seems not to work for stuff like that

Additionally to that I have found that when the post box is closed it ceases to exist oO?

Maybe someone here has an idea how to tackle this
I could of course just loop an operation that sets the style every second or so. but no thanks XD

thanks a lot for helping :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mutation events are deprecated, DOMAttrModified is not and [will not be](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8191) supported by webkit browsers. Use [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FMutationObserver) instead. Alternatively, you can try [this workaround](https://web.archive.org/web/20131005173328/http://engineering.silkapp.com/post/31921750832/mutation-events-what-happens).

Comment: woah thanks a lot :D
this worked awesome, after I found some other stray bug in my extension
thanks again, you helped a lot

Answer (score 5):

To get you quickly started with using **[Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe)**
here's a small reusable function

```js
/**
 * Mutation Observer Helper function
 * //developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe
 * @param {string} sel The DOM selector to watch 
 * @param {object} opt MutationObserver options 
 * @param {function} cb Pass Mutation object to a callback function
 */
const Observe = (sel, opt, cb) => {
  const Obs = new MutationObserver((m) => [...m].forEach(cb));
  document.querySelectorAll(sel).forEach(el => Obs.observe(el, opt));
};
```

To track only attribute `"style"` changes on some `class="item"` Elements, **use like**:

```js
Observe(".item", {
  attributesList: ["style"], // Only the "style" attribute
  attributeOldValue: true,   // Report also the oldValue
}, (m) => {
  console.log(m);            // Mutation object
});
```

To watch for **all attributes** changes, instead of the `attributesList` Array use :

```
attributes: true
```

If needed, here's an example:

```js
/**
 * Mutation Observer Helper function
 * //developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe
 * @param {string} sel The DOM selector to watch 
 * @param {object} opt MutationObserver options 
 * @param {function} cb Pass Mutation object to a callback function
 */
const Observe = (sel, opt, cb) => {
  const Obs = new MutationObserver((m) => [...m].forEach(cb));
  document.querySelectorAll(sel).forEach(el => Obs.observe(el, opt));
};

// DEMO TIME:
Observe("#test", {
  attributesList: ["style"], 
  attributeOldValue: true,
}, (m) => {
  console.log(`
    Old value: ${m.oldValue}
    New value: ${m.target.getAttribute(m.attributeName)}
  `);
});

const EL_test = document.querySelector("#test");
EL_test.addEventListener("input", () => EL_test.style.cssText = EL_test.value);
EL_test.style.cssText = EL_test.value;
```

```css
* {margin:0;}
textarea {width: 60%;height: 50px;}
```

```html
<textarea id="test">
background: #0bf;
color: #000;
</textarea>
```