# Custom PNG mouse cursor with JS

Tags: javascript, icons, styles, cursor

I want to change my mouse cursor on a web page with JS.
My problem is: how do I change one icon to default mode and a different icon to pointer mode.
I tried to do this :

```
document.documentElement.style.cursor = 'url("https://www.happygourmet.co.uk/img/icon_plus.png"), default';
document.documentElement.style.cursor = 'url("https://img.icons8.com/emoji/72/camping.png"), pointer';
```

The problem here is that only the last line of the mouse pointer works and I don't see the first icon.

EDIT :
As there is a different curser by default for default (arrow) and pointer (hand) I want 2 different PNGs here as well for default and for pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Your second line of code has overwritten the first line of code, so you can't see the first icon.

Is your idea to display different cursor styles in different positions on the page? You need to create different element containers separately, and then use `addEventListener` to listen. Here is the code snippet:

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x632tnbj/10/

html:

```html
<div>
  <div id="default-mode"></div>
  <div id="pointer-mode"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```css
#default-mode {
  width: 300;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#pointer-mode {
  width: 300;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

js:

```js
const defaultBox = document.querySelector('#default-mode');
const pointerBox = document.querySelector('#pointer-mode');

defaultBox.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    document.documentElement.style.cursor = 'url("https://www.happygourmet.co.uk/img/icon_plus.png"), default';
});

pointerBox.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    document.documentElement.style.cursor = 'url("https://img.icons8.com/emoji/72/camping.png"), pointer';
});
```

**EDIT:**
Just add the class name `cursor-default` or `cursor-pointer` to the elements. In fact, this idea is the same as my previous answer, except that all elements with cursor-default and cursor-pointer are listened to.

```html
 <div>
  <div id="default-mode1" class="cursor-default"></div>
  <div id="pointer-mode1" class="cursor-pointer"></div>
  <div id="default-mode2" class="cursor-default"></div>
  <div id="pointer-mode2" class="cursor-pointer"></div>
 </div>
```

```js
const defaultElements = document.querySelectorAll('.cursor-default');
const pointerElements = document.querySelectorAll('.cursor-pointer');

defaultElements.forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        document.documentElement.style.cursor = 'url("https://www.happygourmet.co.uk/img/icon_plus.png"), default';
    });
});

pointerElements.forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        document.documentElement.style.cursor = 'url("https://img.icons8.com/emoji/72/camping.png"), pointer';
    });
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3gkr2uc7/

Comment: Thanks but it's not what I need. As there is a different curser by default for default (arrow ) and pointer (hand) I want 2 different PNGs here as well for default and for pointer. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: What about using `MutationObserver`? Listen to the style of elements if contains `cursor: default` or `cursor: pointer` then change the `document.documentElement.style.cursor`.

Comment: Sounds good. Maybe you have an example because I don't know it.

Comment: I have edited the answer. If it still does not match your needs, maybe u can check this post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66511880/14877188

Comment: Because we are modifying at the application layer, we need a `class` or other things to identify the corresponding element to change the cursor image.